# What's the most efficient way to copy all data from Socrata to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, socrata

I am massing copying government open data to BigQuery, see https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/freeopendata-161213:copy_of_socrata_data and https://github.com/wayeasycorp/FreeOpenData/blob/master/etl/socrata/copy_all_datasets.py What's a more efficient way of doing this? There are 34,794 tables on Socrata to copy over. Only 412 have been copied over

Comment: I can see that there is data already in the tables. So, what did you do to get it in?

Comment: @GrahamPolley there are 34794 tables on Socrata to copy over. Only 412 have been copied over.

Comment: So how did you copy the existing 412 tables then?

Comment: @GrahamPolley using the very inefficient script I wrote mentioned in the question https://github.com/wayeasycorp/FreeOpenData/blob/master/etl/socrata/copy_all_datasets.py